# Read Local Text File in Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have data in text format and that text format is located in my app local file. I did my research but I couldn't find anything about it. How to read that text file in swift? Should i use Sqlite or normal text file format with NSBundle? I hope someone help me to start something with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will place the contents of the file into a string:

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "txt");
let fileData = String(filePath!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error:nil)!
```

Comment: Thank you that's what i asking for. This answer is very helpfull for me Thank you again

Answer (score -1):

```
var filePath  = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("world_country_state", ofType:"json")
        var nsMutData = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath!)
        var sJson     = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nsMutData!, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSMutableDictionary
        let arraycOuntry: NSArray = sJson.valueForKey("world")?.allKeys as! NSArray
        let states: NSArray = sJson.valueForKey("world")?.valueForKey("USA") as! NSArray

pickerDataSoruce = states.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

In this Code world_country_state.json is My File just You replace your file name.
i think this Code is very helpful for you.
```

Comment: Should i convert my txt file in the json file?

Comment: no its not necessary. i will converted because i have json File.